# How to display [Object] in Telegram bot Nodejs

Tags: node.js

[in Telegram bot it only shows The current price of [object object]

[image: 1]

```
await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, `The current price of ${_coinList}.`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `_coinList` is an object of some sort. Try to send it as `JSON.stringify(_coinList)` and see what that object looks like.

so you should try the following:

```
await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, The current price of ${JSON.stringify(_coinList)}.);
```

From here you should see the structure of the object and choose the correct key in the object. For example:

```
await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, The current price of ${_coinList.eth}.);
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help! Remember to upvote and mark my answer as accepted if it answered your question!

Answer (score 0):

await bot.sendMessage(chat_id, `The current price of ${JSON.stringify(_coinList)}.`);
this will work.